# How to extract date time from GUID in c#?

Tags: c#, guid

How to extract date time from `GUID` in `C#` ?

Is there any way to get datetime from `GUID` in `C#`?

Comment: What makes you think that a GUID contains datetime information in the first place?  Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: How did you put a datetime in the GUID in the first place?

Comment: Hi. Maybe you wank to create some kind of Primary Key, a unique value for an entity/object. If this is the case, your question is wrong. You can create a unique ID converting peaces of data and concatenate some DateTime conversion.
`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");`

Answer (score 3):

IIRC the date/time *used* to be part of a GUID. Originally, a Guid was constructed from the current date and time combined with the MAC address of the computer that generated them. So this was guaranteed to be unique (since the MAC address is unique). Later - I guess due to data protection considerations - this scheme was abandonned and some random seed was added on top of it. So it is no longer possible to gain any information on who or when a GUID was created.